# Rails Server Exiting `close': Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eventmachine

I keep running into this error when i start up the rails server for this application.
I cannot find any solutions online for this error. Can anyone help?

OS: Windows 7

Let me know if you need any other files?

```
C:\Ruby2\projects\csa>rails s --binding=127.0.0.1
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.5 application starting in development on http://127.0.0.1:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_avlse to avoid this message.
Thin web server (v1.6.2 codename Doc Brown)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 127.0.0.1:3000, CTRL+C to stop
Exiting
C:/Ruby2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3-x86-mingw32/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:330:in `close': Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)
    from C:/Ruby2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3-x86-mingw32/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:330:in `block in run'
    from C:/Ruby2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3-x86-mingw32/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:330:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3-x86-mingw32/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:330:in `ensure in run'
    from C:/Ruby2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3-x86-mingw32/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:333:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3-x86-mingw32/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:62:in `run_machine'
    from C:/Ruby2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3-x86-mingw32/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
    from C:/Ruby2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from C:/Ruby2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from C:/Ruby2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```